# github collaboration pull request

Tags: github, git-pull, collaboration

I am the admin of a github repo. I have added a collaborator with my project, he has done some changes and pushed it in the repo correctly. But how do I get the updated code in my local PC/ VS code?

I tried to clone but not worked,

Comment: It depends if they work from a fork or in a branch on your repository.

Answer (score 1):

Run `git pull` command in your working dir. Or, in the VSCode source control, click the "..." and choose "pull". Then you will get updated.
See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull/en for more detail.
[image: vscode-git-pull]